# Javascript Show/Hide certain elements by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, show-hide

I have 12 tiles (100px by 100px squares) on my screen.

Each tile by default is set to `display:block` and has a white background `background: rgb(255,255,255);`

If a tile is clicked, the background becomes orange `rgb(255,161,53)`. Using the following function:

```
function changeColour(id){
{
    var current_bg = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;

    if(current_bg != "rgb(255, 161, 53)"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,161,53)";
    } else if(current_bg == "rgb(255, 161, 53)"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the page I have a button called **"showHide"**, once it is pressed I want only the tiles with an orange background to be shown. Once it pressed again I want ALL of the tiles to appear.

Comment: Right, and what have you tried?

Comment: Try setting some meta data on your tiles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant with meta data

A break down:

1. The first block iterates over every tile and sets an onclick handler
2. When you click a block it will either set `orange` to the class list or remove it using toggle. The actual orange coloring comes from the stylesheet. Where tiles that don't have `orange` in their class names `:not()` get a white background.
3. When you click the show hide button you'll see the same trick. Every class list that doesn't contain `orange` get hidden by the `hide` class name that gets toggled.

I've used a different approach here, using class names as selectors and play with them to get the desired result.

```js
function changeColour() {
  this.classList.toggle("orange");

  //if hiding is on we need to also hide that block
  if (this.parentElement.querySelectorAll("div.tiles.hide").length > 0)
  {
    this.classList.add("hide");
  }
}

var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.tiles");

//use Array.prototype.forEach to iterate over nodelist
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click", changeColour);
});

document.querySelector("button.hide").addEventListener("click", showHide);

function showHide(){
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(element){
    
    if (!element.classList.contains("orange"))
    {
      element.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
  });  
}
```

```css
div.tiles {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div.tiles:not(.orange) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.tiles.orange {
  background-color: rgb(255,161,53);
}

div.tiles.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles"></div>
<div class="tiles"></div>
<div class="tiles"></div>
<div class="tiles"></div>
<div class="tiles"></div>

<button class="hide">show/hide white tiles</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However if you unselect an orange tile when the white ones are hidden it breaks.

Also, can you put this in a function called showHide() please.

Comment: Thanks, added some logic!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Could you put this in a function called showHide() which is an onclick event on the "show/hide white tiles" button please.

Comment: Thank you again. Yes I have, I was almost there, I just needed a hand with reshowing the white ones that had been unselected.